# Mobicents SIP Servlets on OpenShift

Tags: tomcat7, openshift, mobicents-sip-servlets

How can I install Mobicents SIP Servlets/Tomcat7 on OpenShift?
Is there any cartridge for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. The issue is that we would need to open signalling ports for SIP on 5060 or the likes which is not allowed AFAIR. But you can double check again if they allow other ports apart HTTP ones to be opened.